# Screen Capture Using c#

Tags: c#, screen-capture

I have tried capturing the screen using the following. But it is throwing '**Exception was thrown from the UITest module**' exception.

```
System.Drawing.Image image;
BrowserWindow win = new BrowserWindow();
image = win.CaptureImage();
String ErrorFile = "D:\\TestLog\\" + errorMsg + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy HH.mm.ss") + ".jpeg";
image.Save(ErrorFile);
```

I am not able to understand why the exception was showing
. It was working perfectly before. 
[image]

This is what I am doing with this code

**I am using this code in the testcase failure condition. If that test case is failed Iam captureing the browser screenshot and save it in D:/testlog folder.**

Comment: Can you post exception details?

Comment: Edit was not helpful. We need name of the exception, message and stacktrace. and which line throws the exception?

Comment: Need more details for e.g. InnerException details

Comment: This is what it is showing.And the exception was on `image = win.CaptureImage();` line and `image.Save(ErrorFile);` line

Comment: I am geting InnerException as null. I have updated the question with the screenshot of the error

Comment: Ok for the question, we are analyzing it. But are you creating a browser and saving ad image to save an erroe? This isn't the right way for error lgging!

Comment: I am using this code in the testcase failure condition. If that test case is failed Iam captureing the browser screenshot and save it in D:/testlog folder.